# Does File.realpath() leak memory?

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble with File.realpath() leaving strings around that don't seem to get garbage collected. It looks to me like a memory leak, though I can't imagine such a thing actually being true for a core library method.

Consider the following code:

```
def string_test(string)
  puts string
end


GC.start
report = MemoryProfiler.report do
   s = './foo.txt'.freeze
   string_test(s)
   s = nil
   GC.start
end
report.pretty_print
```

This yields (among other verbose output):

```
Total allocated: 0 bytes (0 objects)
Total retained:  0 bytes (0 objects)
```

So far so good, there seems to be no residual memory usage from calling the string_test() method. However, if I change the method to resolve the relative path as follows:

```
def string_test(string)
  puts File.realpath(string)
end
```

I get the following output from MemoryProfiler:

```
Total allocated: 128 bytes (2 objects)
Total retained:  88 bytes (1 objects)
.
.
.
Retained String Report
-----------------------------------
          1  "/home/asdfjk/tmp/foo.txt"
          1  t:28
```

foo.txt is a symbolic link to the actual file. I don't know if that's relevant or not. It seems File.realpath() is leaving a copy of the string around. Aggregate this over hundreds of thousands of files and it chews up a lot of memory. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here and possibly how to fix it?

Another interesting tidbit is that in the first example (the one that doesn't leak), string s must be frozen, or the result is the same as the version including the call to File.realpath().

Comment: version of ruby?

Comment: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: Instead of allocating one string, try making a million, calling `GC.start`, and checking. The garbage collector might not do anything because there's not enough work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I tested using `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]` and the file `./foo.txt` which is a symlink too `./foo`.

If we cut your example down to the bare-minimum necessary, then the answer is no, there is no memory leak in `File.realpath`:

```
require 'memory_profiler'
MemoryProfiler.report { puts File.realpath('./foo.txt') }.pretty_print
<snip>
Retained String Report
-----------------------------------
```

The issues you're seeing come down to a combination of your calls to `GC.start`, `.freeze` and the way `MemoryProfiler` measures these things within a code block.

As for why `puts string` and `puts File.realpath(string)` behave differently, `puts string` reads the value of `string` and prints it to the console; `puts File.realpath(string)` *creates* a new `String` object then prints it to the console.

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. thank you for the clarification. it is much appreciated